# Referencing array values

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I have been faced with the following issue.

```
create type some_ty as object(
s_id number
);

create table some_tbl of some_ty;

insert into some_tbl values(1);
insert into some_tbl values(2);
insert into some_tbl values(3);

create type some_arr as varray(5) of number;

create type test_ty as object(
t_id number,
array some_arr
) ;

create table test_tbl of test_ty;

insert into test_tbl values(10, some_arr(1,2,3,4));
```

My question is if there is an sql way to check if the values of `some_arr` are exist in `some_tbl`? Because now it inserts "4" as well which is not a record of `some_tbl`.

I cannot use ref on varray.

I have managed to do this using pl/sql loop. I just want to know if there is an easy way for that.

Comment: One of the limitations of objects is data integrity. If you want to enforce relational integrity you should build regular tables with a foreign key.

Comment: The problem is that there is a restriction of records for the array. Example student and class. one class can have maximum 10 students. and with many-many table i cannot do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an [Object-Relational database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/toc.htm) and want to to have a reference to another object then use a [`REF`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions127.htm). You can use this in a `VARRAY`:

```
create type some_ty as object( s_id number );
/

create table some_tbl of some_ty;

insert into some_tbl values(1);
insert into some_tbl values(2);
insert into some_tbl values(3);

create or replace type some_arr as varray(5) of REF some_ty;
/

create type test_ty as object(
  t_id  number,
  t_list some_arr
);
/

create table test_tbl of test_ty(
  t_list CONSTRAINT test_tbl__t_list__nn NOT NULL
);

-- Collection to allow a variable length list to be passed to the insert.
CREATE TYPE INTLIST AS TABLE OF INTEGER;
/

insert into test_tbl values(
  10,
  (
    SELECT CAST( COLLECT( REF(t) ORDER BY s_id ) AS some_arr )
    FROM   some_tbl t
    WHERE  s_id MEMBER OF INTLIST( 1,2,3,4 )
    HAVING COUNT(*) = CARDINALITY( INTLIST( 1,2,3,4 ) ) -- Ensure all items are matched
  )
);
```

Would throw an error for violating the `NOT NULL` constraint but:

```
insert into test_tbl values(
  10,
  (
    SELECT CAST( COLLECT( REF(t) ORDER BY s_id ) AS some_arr )
    FROM   some_tbl t
    WHERE  s_id MEMBER OF INTLIST( 1,2,3 )
    HAVING COUNT(*) = CARDINALITY( INTLIST( 1,2,3 ) ) -- Ensure all items are matched
  )
);
```

Would work and you could then do:

```
SELECT t.t_id, DEREF( l.COLUMN_VALUE ).s_id
FROM   test_tbl t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE( t.t_list ) l
       ON ( 1 = 1 );
```

Outputs:

```
      T_ID              DEREF(L.COLUMN_VALUE).S_ID
---------- ---------------------------------------
        10                                       1
        10                                       2
        10                                       3
```

Comment: hi. it looks like almost there. For some reason when i insert value which does not exist in another table it does not give any error. It just ignores the value and inserts the others which is no good. Example i insert 4 values, 1,2,3,4 but only 1 exist it inserts 1 only. It should give an error thought.

Comment: @bontoo Added a solution that will throw an error if not all the items are matched - it will throw an exception for violating the `NOT NULL` constraint rather than any referential constraints (which can't exist on a `VARRAY` or a nested table) but it is pure SQL.

Comment: Hi! Ok now its working. You are so advanced of this stuff that i have no idea whats going on the code. I mean it is clear from the notes but still I need to do some research to understand them. Like cardinality(i have never used before) and why used ON(1=1). I have never seen this just with attributes like t_id=s_id. So it is good to learn new things and thank you so much for your help MTO!

Comment: @bontoo Here is the [`CARDINALITY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions015.htm) documentation. You could use `CROSS JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but then if the `VARRAY` was empty then the row would not appear - using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is just in case you ever have an empty array and the `1=1` insures the join condition will always be met.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to encapsulate the lookup into a constructor function.

```
create or replace type test_ty as object(
  t_id number,
  array some_arr ,
  constructor function test_ty (self in out test_ty
             , t_id number
             , array some_arr)  
    return self as result        
) ;
/

create or replace type body test_ty as 

  constructor function test_ty (self in out test_ty
             , t_id number
             , array some_arr)  
    return self as result        
    is
        n number;
    begin
        for idx in array.first() .. array.last
        loop
            select s_id into n
            from some_tbl
            where s_id = array(idx);
        end loop;
        self.t_id := t_id;
        self.array := array;
        return;         
    exception 
        when no_data_found then
           raise_application_error(-20099, 'array contains invalid value');     
    end test_ty ;
end ;
/
```

Here is how to invoke it:

```
SQL> insert into test_tbl values(test_ty(9, some_arr(1,2,3)));

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test_tbl values(test_ty(10, some_arr(1,2,3,4)));
insert into test_tbl values(test_ty(10, some_arr(1,2,3,4)))
                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20099: array contains invalid value
ORA-06512: at "FOX.TEST_TY", line 21


SQL>
```

Note that you need to use the type explicitly to invoke the constructor:

```
SQL> insert into test_tbl values(10, some_arr(1,2,3,4));

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

> "Example student and class. one class can have maximum 10 students. and with many-many table i cannot do that."

Well, you could do it like this:

```
create table class_student (
    class_id number not null 
    , student_id number not null 
    , attendee_no number(2,0) not null 
    , constraint class_student_pk 
        primary key (class_id, student_id, attendee_no) 
    , constraint class_student_ck
        check (attendee_no between 1 and 10 ) 
    , constraint class_student_class_fk 
        foreign key (class_id) references class 
    , constraint class_student_student_fk 
        foreign key (student_id) references student
);
```

Comment: Thanks APC!The constructor function works really good! I did a procedure for that which was worked already but was not "self" function. This approach even better for what i needed then what MTO gave me but that was good as well.(the question was anyway to solve this in pure sql way) I am really happy for the helps! But i already gave the mark for MTO answer which was one way to solve this. Really appropriate for all the helps! Thank you!

Comment: You can still upvote my answer even though you accepted MT0's one :)